# How to add a password input form into osascript dialogue from a Mac/UNIX

Tags: macos, popup, applescript

I have

```
set theAlertText to "An error has occurred."
set theAlertMessage to "System would like to update Keychain privacy certificate. Please enter your Apple ID password"
display alert theAlertText message theAlertMessage as critical buttons {"Continue"} default button "Continue"
```

[image]

I would like to add hidden answer field

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `display dialog` instead of `display alert`.

```
display dialog "Please enter a passphrase to use this script." default answer "" with icon stop buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue" with hidden answer
```

from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/PromptforText.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH80-SW1

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that too from the exact same page, this will open 2 different windows. I was hoping to put it all in one pop up box

Comment: I think I figured out something else :)